# Is it possible to modify number of workers/threads in an existing distributed client?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm optimizing a TPOT pipeline with dask on my local machine. I expect this to run for 48 hrs or even more.

I started a client with a few cores so I can continue using my machine while it's running in the background.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=6, memory_limit="14GB")
```

I'm wondering if I could add workers/threads to the client so it has increased computing capacity when I'm sleeping or not using my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you might consider using Dask's Adaptive scaling: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/adaptive.html

```
client.cluster.adapt(minimum=0, maximum=10)
```

Comment: I was able to throttle up and down using
`client.cluster.adapt(minimum_cores=11, maximum_cores=11, maximum_memory="14GB")` and `client.cluster.adapt(minimum_cores=6, maximum_cores=6, maximum_memory="14GB")`. I can see this happening in the dashboard.

But tt seems that throttling up increases the memory to 26 GB. I notice that the cluster becomes 2 workers of 6 threads each. Is there a way to make it explicit that I want 1 worker of 12 threads when I throttle up?

Comment: I've also tried using `KubeCluster`. It seems the video demo is outdated... I tried following the docs using `KubeCluster.from_yaml` and using `make_pod_spec` but it both gave `ConfigException: Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found.`

Comment: The only reliable way I've found to keep the memory within physical limits is by instantiating the client without parameters `client = Client()` and use adapt as stated above...